# ElasticSearch: No subject alternative names matching IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 found

Tags: elasticsearch, sslhandshakeexception

When I start my ES nodes, I've been seeing the message `client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection` and the following exception.
Anybody knows what it is about? After some seconds the exceptions stop and the clsuter seems to work ok.

Thanks.

```
[2020-06-18T22:11:09,608][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [my-es-hostname] publish_address {172.55.55.55:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2020-06-18T22:11:09,623][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [my-es-hostname] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2020-06-18T22:11:10,769][WARN ][o.e.t.TcpTransport       ] [my-es-hostname] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51060, remoteAddress=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9300}], closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 found
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:473) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:600) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:554) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) [netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 found
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1331) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1206) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1153) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runAllDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1502) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1516) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1400) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 found
[2020-06-18T22:11:10,837][WARN ][o.e.x.c.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4Transport] [my-es-hostname] client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9300, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:43784}
[2020-06-18T22:11:10,848][WARN ][o.e.t.TcpTransport       ] [my-es-hostname] exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:43784, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:9300}], closing connection
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem with Elasticsearch 8.6.2.

Solved by setting `network.publish_host` to FQDN in the `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: es-42.acme.tld  # <-- this
```

[network.publish_host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings) tells other cluster members how to connect to this node. By default it's the same value as `network.host`, so in my case other cluster nodes were connecting to this one using IP address.

If TLS is enabled, the address where nodes are connecting should be listed in the certificate subject DN to pass the verification. So there are two options:

1. Change `network.publish_host` to FQDN, as above (if certificate subject DN contains this hostname or domain wildcard)
2. Add IP address to the certificate subject DN -- didn't test, but that should also work